# Given a pair $(\zeta^2,v)$ find a pair $(\zeta^3,w)$ where there's an embedding $e:\zeta^2 \hookrightarrow \zeta^3$ s.t. $v=e^*w$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-analysis, vector-fields, pullback

I would like to take a pair $(\zeta^2,v)$ and find a pair $(\zeta^3,w)$ where there is an embedding $e: \zeta^2 \hookrightarrow \zeta^3$ such that $v=e^*w.$

Define the manifold $\zeta^2:=(0,1)^2$ and vector field $v:=\langle x\log x, -y\log y\rangle,$ for $x,y \in(0,1).$

Due to the comment below...$w$ should be a 3-vector field accumulating to each of the eight vertices and non-vanishing elsewhere. (source is at $(1,0,0)$ and sink is at $(0,1,1)$).

**Attempt:**

Lift $(\zeta^2,v)$ onto a parallelogram so that it's embedding in  $\zeta^3$ spans the long diagonal of $\zeta^3,$ as opposed to sitting at the base of the cube (approximate sketch above).

Then $w$ should restrict onto the lifted $(\zeta^2,v).$ I'm thinking of this parallelogram as being bent/curved whilst the $(0,1,1)$ and $(1,0,0)$ points stay fixed. On each of these templates in the parameter space will be $v$ but it will sit on manifolds of varying curvatures.

Finally take the collection of these vector fields $v_i$, to get $w.$

This is only an attempt and may not be the correct way to approach the problem.

> How do we arrive at the pair $(\zeta^3,w)?$

If for example $\zeta^2$ is defined to be the closed 2-disk, $D^2,$ then one example for $v$ is $v(p) := \frac{1}{r-\|p\|}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(p).$ Where $r$ is the radius of the disk.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but your superscripts leave me baffled. What's $\zeta^2$? What's $\zeta^3$?

Comment: I defined the manifold $\zeta^2:= (0,1)^2$

Comment: $\zeta^3:=(0,1)^3$

Comment: Does that clarify?

Comment: $(1)\ v$ has four isolated zeros on $[0,1]^2$ and $(2)\ w$ has two isolated zeros at two vertices of farthest distance in unit cube ? And (3) $v$ in example has an infinite length on the boundary of unit ball ?

Comment: How are you getting four isolated zeros?...doesn't $v:=\langle x\log x, -y\log y\rangle$ accumulate to only two points $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$? If it does have four accumulation points on $[0,1]^2$ (at the four vertices) then $w$ should have accumulation points at the 8 vertices of $[0,1]^3$

Comment: ${\rm lim}_{x\rightarrow 0 } x{\rm log}\ x=0,\ {\rm lim}_{x\rightarrow 1}  x{\rm log}\ x=0$ so that $v$ has four isolated zeroes.

Comment: What is the definition of accumulating ?

Comment: @HKLee https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulation_point#Definition

Comment: A surface  accumulates to a point  if  lies in the closure of  but not in  itself.

Comment: I see accumulation point definition which  I have already known. You have written ' 3-vector field accumulating to each of the eight vertices ' You mean that the vector field has zeroes at each vertex ?

Comment: @HKLee yes $w$ has zeroes at each vertex

Comment: with the source (unstable node) at $(1,0,0)$ and sink (stable node) at $(0,1,1)$ @HKLee

Comment: Lastly, I want to check the following : $w$ should be tangent to the boundary surface of $[0,1]^3$ ?

Comment: @HKLee does your answer assume $w$ is tangent to the boundary?

Comment: Yes. Consider a plane $x=0$. Then $W(0,y,z)=(0,-y{\rm log}y,-z{\rm log}\ z)$ so that $W\cdot (1,0,0)=0$ Hence $(1,0,0)$ is normal to the plane $x=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e(x,y)=(x,y,0)$ (possibly $ (x,y,1))$ and define $$ W(x,y,z)=\bigg(x{\rm log}x,-y{\rm log}y,-z{\rm log}z  \bigg) $$

Then $de\ \frac{\partial }{\partial x} = (1,0,0),\ de\  \frac{\partial }{\partial y} 
 = (0,1,0) $ so that $$ (de\ V)(x,y,0)=W(x,y,0) $$ where $V=(x{\rm log}x,-y{\rm log}y)$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Any idea if $W$ is Killing? I ask because $V$ is Killing (it preserves the pseudo metric $g=\frac{dxdt}{xt}$)

Comment: Also is it possible to embed 6 copies of $V$ onto the boundary faces of $[0,1]^3$ and require the pullback along each embedding to equal that specific copy?

Comment: By considering map $f: (x,y)\mapsto (x,c,y)$ where $c=0$ or $1$, faces corresponded to
$y=0,\ y=1$ are copies of $V$. But I am not sure that faces
corresponded to $x=0,\ x=1$ are also copies

Comment: Note that pseudo metric is symmetry. Hence $g=\frac{1}{xt} dxdt$ is not pseudo. If you want to consider $h=\frac{1}{xt} (dxxdt+dtdx)$, then it is in fact metric. Furthermore, I want to know what metric $V$ is Killing.

Comment: No $g=\frac{dxdt}{xt}$ is a pseudo-riemannian metric for $x,t>0$. It describes Minkowski space in different coordinates. And $V=(x\log x,-y\log y)$ is Killing for $g.$ Which is why I'd like to find out if $(\zeta^3,w)$ is some generalisation of $(\zeta^2,v).$

Comment: $g = \frac{1}{xt} (dxdt +dtdx) $ ? And furthermore could you explain why the vector field $V$ is Killing wrt $g$ ?

Comment: basically because the pullback of $(\zeta^2,g)$ by diffeomorphism $f(x,t)=(\log x, \log t)$ yields a semi-riemannian manifold which can be identified as Minkowski 2-space. Since these manifolds are equivalent by diffeomorphism, we can observe the correspondence of Killing fields i.e. $V$ preserving $g_1=\frac{dxdt}{xt}$ and the pulled back version of $V$, namely $X=(x,-t)$ preserving $g_2=dxdt.$